# jquery filter content from inner div

Tags: jquery

Right now I have a feature that filters divs based on the content that is within. However, at the moment it filters based on everything that is inside that main div container (in this example, `div class="name"`). However, I would like it to filter instead by a div that is within that div (in this example, `div class="addresss"`).

I would like something that accomplishes what I am trying to do in this code below.

```
$(document).on('click', '#run', function(){
var comment = "Street Place";    
var searching = $('.name').children('.address:contains('+comment.value+')');  
searching.filter(':contains('+comment.value+')').show();    
});
```

For this example, I want my Run function to show the entire div based on its compatibility with `var comment`, which so happens to have the same info as `div address.`

JsFiddle Link
https://jsfiddle.net/4xe28x5z/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Below is the modified code

$(document).on('click', '#run', function(){
var comment = "Street Place";    
var searching = $('.name').children('.address:contains('+comment+')');  
searching.filter(':contains('+comment+')').closest('.name').show();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4xe28x5z/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:has()` filter with `:contains()` to filter `name` based on `address` like

```js
$(document).on('click', '#run', function() {
  var comment = "Street Place";
  var searching = $('.name').has('.address:contains("' + comment + '")');
  searching.show();
});
```

```css
.name {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="name">
  <p>Mr Sample</p>
  <div class="address">Street Place</div>
</div>
<div class="name">
  <p>Mr Sample</p>
  <div class="address">some Place</div>
</div>
<div class="name">
  <p>Mr Sample</p>
  <div class="address">other Place</div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Run" id="run" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery `:has` to filter

```js
$(document).on('click', '#run', function () {
  var comment = "Street Place";
  var searching = $('.name').has('.address:contains(' + comment + ')');
  searching.show();
});
```

```css
 .name {
   display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="name">
  <p>Mr Sample</p>
  <div class="address">Street Place</div>
</div>
<div class="name">
  <p>Mr Sample 2</p>
  <div class="address">Street Place 2</div>
</div>
<div class="name">
  <p>Mr Sample 3</p>
  <div class="address">Street Palace</div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Run" id="run" />
```